# Parse Push (Installation Class) - Count subscribers that belong to more than 1 channel

Tags: parse-platform, push-notification, parse-cloud-code

I'm using Parse for push notifications. I have seen questions on how to count the number of subscribers of a particular channel.

My question is how do I count the number of subscribers that belong to more than 1 channel?

Ideally, I'd be able to do something like:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("multipleSubscribersNum", function(request, response){

Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
query.greaterThan("channels.length", 2);
query.count({
    success:function(count){
        response.success(count);
    },
    error:function(){
        response.error("Some error");
    }
});
});
```

Obviously, this doesn't work but hopefully it illustrates what I want to do. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ParseClient::initialize( $APPLICATION_ID,$REST_API,$MASTER_KEY );
$query = new ParseQuery("_Installation");
try
{
    $query->equalTo( 'channels','YOUR_CHANNEL' );
    $count = $query->count( true );
    echo"<pre>";echo __FILE__ . " - LINHA: " . __LINE__;echo " : ";print_r( $count );exit;
}
catch( ParseException $ex ){}
```